# What's the proper way to fetch the score of all answers of SO?

Tags: support, api, questions, api-v2.2

I wrote [a small program](https://github.com/Canop/skillrep/blob/master/core%2Fmain.go#L15) querying the SE API to grab the public scoring data of all SO answers (excluding the last 3 days).

Basically the request I do gets me this:

```
 Questions[]:
    Id
    Title
    Tags
    CreationDate
    Owner:
        Id
        Name
    Answers[]:
        Id
        CreationDate
        Owner:
            Id
            Name
        Score
```

Here's an example of the queries I do (API key removed):

> http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow&filter=!OfYUQYtgCaZ9JBeJyrvLd85AXer(WSNHQacu))0iZzl&sort=creation&order=asc&page=2580&fromdate=1229368998&todate=1433795169

The problem is: This processus is too slow to get me everything. I receive 30 questions per response of the API. I'm allowed 10,000 requests per day. So it would take me a long time to get up with the site and have all questions.

I'm also asked to backoff for 10 seconds after every request, so I suppose it's heavy for the server.

Here are my questions:

- Is some part of my request too heavy ?
- Is there a better approach ?

Comment: Thanks to a hint given by Benjamin Gruenbaum, I'm downloading a [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) (27GB) to try to do an initial filling of my DB.

Comment: Note that the dump wouldn't really solve the problem, only make it a little smaller.